# Sound when Brakes are applied

Tags: honda, brakes

I have 2017 Honda BRV, petrol. I hadn't driven it for last couple of days, yesterday when I started my car to go office, I heard a sound as if something is loosen up! I taught as if the tire was flat but when I inspected all the tires to find nothing wrong with them. I taught of driving further more and I realized the sound is coming when the brakes are applied. Has anybody encountered this problem?  What may be the cause?

Comment: It might break the bank if the brakes are broken, so i hope its not the case... 

Ok enough about spelling. Your description is quite vague. Maybe you can record the sound or describe it a bit better? Is there also vibration when you apply the brakes?

Comment: @MadMarky - English is most likely not this user's first language, but I've edited to correct the spelling.

Comment: Maybe just worn; either the warning scraper , or ( very bad) metal to metal , backer to rotor/drum.

Answer (score 1):

When a vehicle stands for some time, the brake-discs begin to rust.

Normally this rust-layer gets quickly worn off, if you use your breaks again. You can aid this by doing some controlled breaks where you first break gently and then firmer and from higher speed. (Watch for traffic - don´t cause an accident!)

In extreme cases, you brake can rust to the point where you need to replace the discs.

A special consideration with this is the handbrakes: If you have you vehicle standing for a longer time, the pads can rust to the discs. So for letting your Vehicle stand for a longer time, best not to apply the handbrakes. Better find somewhat even ground and put in first gear - (P) if have automatic.